# How to clean off spray adhesive?

Tags: adhesives

This probably comes up more often than people would like, but how does one clean spray adhesive (at least the 3M brand) from various materials? In particular fabric or self-healing cutting mats?

Comment: I suspect the items you are tying to clean are going to dictate the methods used.  So the question should focus more on what you want to clean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Always make sure to test any solvents on a piece that you don't mind ruining first***

Man-made fibers and plastics can interact quite unexpectedly with solvents. Since most 3M spray adhesives aren't water soluable (per the MSDS), solvents are going to be the trick for removing overspray.

[PerfectFit.com](http://www.perfectfit.com/24783/155885/Upholstery-Adhesives/3M-Super-77-Super-Spray-Adhesive.html) has some good suggestions:

> **Removing overspray**. Adhesive overspray is always better prevented than
>   removed. But several common solvents can help clean it off, including
>   mineral spirits, turpentine, citrus-based cleaners or 3M™ Adhesive
>   Remover. Be sure to follow proper precautionary measures when using
>   solvents!
>
> - **On hands**, apply baby oil, cooking or vegetable oil, followed by soap and water.
> - **On furniture**, use a furniture polish.
> - **On fabrics and carpet**, first remove as much glue as possible with masking tape. Then dab the surface with a cloth dampened with one of
>     the solvents listed above. 
>     Or spraythe surface directly with 3M™ Adhesive Remover or a citrus-based cleaner.
>
> Always test solvents and cleaners on inconspicuous areas of fabric or
>   carpet first.

Answer (score 1):

I removed a little spray adhesive from granite counter with full strength dish detergent on a cloth, followed by water on a paper towel.